# R Script not breaking columns into separate plots

Tags: r, loops, plot

Taking a course on R w/ statistics. Feel quite stupid that I cannot figure this out myself. I have a difficult time when given specific instructions w/ no additional help or examples.

```
load("Dataset")
##variable/vector in "dataset" is x<-- (1000 x 9 table/matrix)
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
## or mfcol
for(i in 1:9){
  qqnorm(x, xlab="t quantiles",ylim=c(-30,30))
}
```

My issue is this spits out 9 plots, but they're all the same plot with the entire 1000x9 matrix calculated on one plot. Clearly I'm missing the correct command to split each column up, but I was told mfrow or mfcol would do this. Is there something within the qqnorm call that will spit out all 9 separate plots are each column of the matrix? Perhaps it's within the loop structure?

Thanks,

-frustrated noob

Comment: It does not look like you are iterating inside the for loop. Can you also post a minimal reproducible example? https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-how-to-do-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-for-beginners/23061

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake when you're just starting out. Use your index (`i`) to subset your matrix

```
for(i in 1:9){
  qqnorm(x[, i], # <=== change is here.  
         xlab="t quantiles",ylim=c(-30,30))
}
```